# Updating object inside a collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this document and I am want to change the status of `messageId: 2` to `read`

```
{
    conversationId: 1,
    message: [
        {
            text: 'Hello World',
            userForm: {
                userId: 1
            },
            userTo: [
                {
                    messageId: 1,
                    userId: 1,
                    status: 'owner'
                },
                {
                    messageId: 2,
                    userId: 2,
                    status: 'not read'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'Hello World',
            userForm: {
                userId: 1
            },
            userTo: [
                {
                    messageId: 3,
                    userId: 1,
                    status: 'owner'
                },
                {
                    messageId: 4,
                    userId: 2,
                    status: 'not read'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried with `updateOne()` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/ but it didn't work.

I'm still new in querying subdocuments in MongoDB. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I Try this: 

conversationSchema.update(
            {
                "messages.userTo.messageId": 2,
                "messages.userTo.userId": 2
            },
            {
                "$set": {
                    "messages.$.userTo.$.status": 'read'
                }
            },
            null,
            function(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        );

Comment: You can use mongoose model method `findOneAndUpdate` [more info](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)